# How to include barcode value with actual barcode Python `code128` module

Tags: python, barcode, code128

I just built a quick Python Azure Function that generates a barcode. The response is ONLY the rendered barcode in .png format. I also need the barcode VALUE to be displayed below it.

**Example:**

```
import logging
import azure.functions as func
import code128
import io
from PIL import Image


barcode_param = '1234'
barcode_bytes = io.BytesIO()

logging.info('##### Generating barcode... #####')
barcode = code128.image(barcode_param, height=100).save(barcode_bytes, "PNG")
barcode_bytes.seek(0)
logging.info('##### Barcode successfully generated #####')
return func.HttpResponse(
    barcode_bytes.getvalue(),
    status_code=200,
    mimetype='image/png'
    )
    barcode_bytes.close()
```

**Generates:**
[image]

**Need:**
[image]
**theseahawksarewinning**

How can I add the barcode **value** to the barcode with the `code128` library?

There are no options shown [in the docs](https://pypi.org/project/code128/).

**EDIT 1: After @Furas great example, I now have:**

[image]

**Code to produce:**

```
import code128
import io
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

# Get barcode value
barcode_param = 'SUFFERINSUCCOTASH'

# Create barcode image
barcode_image = code128.image(barcode_param, height=100)

# Create empty image for barcode + text
top_bott_margin = 70
l_r_margin = 10
new_height = barcode_image.height + (2 * top_bott_margin)
new_width = barcode_image.width + (2 * l_r_margin)
new_image = Image.new( 'RGB', (new_width, new_height), (255, 255, 255))

# put barcode on new image
barcode_y = 100
new_image.paste(barcode_image, (0, barcode_y))

# object to draw text
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(new_image)

# Define custom text size and font
h1_size = 28
h2_size = 28
h3_size = 16
footer_size = 21

h1_font = ImageFont.truetype("DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf", h1_size)
h2_font = ImageFont.truetype("Ubuntu-Th.ttf", h2_size)
h3_font = ImageFont.truetype("Ubuntu-Th.ttf", h3_size)
footer_font = ImageFont.truetype("UbuntuMono-R.ttf", footer_size)

# Define custom text
company_name = 'YAY! CORP.'
id1 = '11-22-33-44'
license_num = 'WHY SOYNTENLY!'
product_type = 'GRADE A GREATNESS'
center_product_type = (barcode_image.width / 2) - len(product_type) * 5
center_barcode_value = (barcode_image.width / 2) - len(barcode_param) * 8

# Draw text on picture
draw.text( (l_r_margin, 0), company_name, fill=(0, 0, 0), font=h1_font)
draw.text( (l_r_margin, h1_size), id1, fill=(0, 0, 0), font=h2_font)
draw.text( (l_r_margin + 2, (h1_size + h2_size + 5)), license_num, fill=(0, 0, 0), font=h3_font)
draw.text( (center_product_type, (h1_size + h2_size + h3_size)), product_type, fill=(0, 0, 0), font=footer_font)
draw.text( (center_barcode_value, (new_height - footer_size - 15)), barcode_param, fill=(0, 0, 0), font=h2_font)

# save in file 
new_image.save('barcode_image.png', 'PNG')

# show in default viewer
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open('barcode_image.png')
```

Thanks mate!

Comment: Maybe you couldn't find an option for it because it doesn't exist.  Can you print the text independently?

Comment: You will have to generate an image of the bar code data and append it below the image of the bar code graphic.  It is probably not a function in the code128 library.  More research required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get code as Pillow image so you can use Pillow to add margin for text and to draw this text.

You can get original size

```
w, h = barcode_image.size
```

calculate new size

```
new_w = w  # the same 

margin = 20
new_h = h + (2*margin)
```

create empty image with white background

```
new_image = Image.new('RGB', (new_w, new_h), (255, 255, 255))
```

put original barcode in the middle of height

```
new_image.paste(barcode_image, (0, margin))
```

Next you can use `ImageDraw` to create object which can draw objects or put text on image

```
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(new_image)
```

and you can put some text using `text()`. You may need to use `ImageFont` to load font and set size. I use default font and size.

```
#fnt = ImageFont.truetype("arial.ttf", 40)
draw.text( (10, new_h - 10), barcode_text, fill=(0, 0, 0))#, font=fnt)
```

and you have image with text in `new_image`. And you can save it in file and check directly in web browser or you can convert to bytes and send to client.

In example I use standard module `webbrowser` only to check image.

[image]

---

**EDIT**

As @RufusVS noted in comment I could use `image_new.show()` instead of `webbrowser`

---

```
import code128
import io
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

barcode_param = '1234'
barcode_text = 'theseahawksarewinning'

# original image
barcode_image = code128.image(barcode_param, height=100)

# empty image for code and text - it needs margins for text
w, h = barcode_image.size
margin = 20
new_h = h +(2*margin) 

new_image = Image.new( 'RGB', (w, new_h), (255, 255, 255))

# put barcode on new image
new_image.paste(barcode_image, (0, margin))

# object to draw text
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(new_image)

# draw text
#fnt = ImageFont.truetype("arial.ttf", 40)
draw.text( (10, new_h - 10), barcode_text, fill=(0, 0, 0))#, font=fnt)  # 

# save in file 
new_image.save('barcode_image.png', 'PNG')

# show in default viewer
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open('barcode_image.png')

# --- later send it---

barcode_bytes = io.BytesIO()
new_image.save(barcode_bytes, "PNG")
barcode_bytes.seek(0)
data = barcode_bytes.getvalue()
```

---

Doc: [Image](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html)
[Image.new()](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.new),
[ImageDraw](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageDraw.html),
[ImageDraw.text()](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageDraw.html#PIL.ImageDraw.ImageDraw.text)
[ImageFont](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageFont.html)

Comment: You can also use i.e.  `new_image.show()` to display the graphic (during development)

Comment: @RufusVS good point - I added this to answer.