# How to convert .png labels to EPL using Python?

Tags: python, epl

I am able to create really nice labels with barcodes using the `code128` and `PIL` modules ([thanks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65471637/how-to-include-barcode-value-with-actual-barcode-python-code128-module) @furas). Now I need to print them out on a Zebra TLP 2824 Plus printer. This thing runs on [EPL](https://support.zebra.com/cpws/docs/eltron/epl2/EPL2_Prog.pdf) (Eltron Programming Language) which is uglier than XML (no offense).

Does anyone have a simple way to convert .png's to EPL using Python?

Comment: Best resources (no python yet) I've found so far are: http://labelary.com/zpl.html, http://labelary.com/viewer.html, https://jsprintmanager.azurewebsites.net/. Still trying to figure out how to tie it all together.

Comment: What you mean with "converting png to EPL"